# how can i show , add fab icon in centre using bottom navigation view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

I have tried this but its not showing fab icon size bigger in centre and used almost solution on this site .
I want to achieve like below youtube bottom centre icon.[image]

```
<!--  Bottom Menu -->
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/home_page_navigation"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:background="@color/background_color"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
    
    
                        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:background="@color/bottom_navigation_view_color"
                            app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_item_primary_color"
                            app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_item_primary_color"
                            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"/>
    
                        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/fab_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_icon"
                            android:tint="@color/colorGray"
                            android:background="@color/bottomcolor"
                            app:borderWidth="0dp"
                            app:elevation="9dp"
                            android:contentDescription="add" />
    
                    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using coordinator layout , might be it will help others. Here is my code

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                        android:id="@+id/home_page_navigation"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
                   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:background="@color/bottom_navigation_view_color"
                            app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_item_primary_color"
                            app:itemTextColor="@color/selector_item_primary_color"
                            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                            app:elevation="0dp"
                            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
                            app:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"/>
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                            android:id="@+id/fab_button"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:contentDescription="add"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_icon"
                            app:backgroundTint="@color/bottom_navigation_view_color"
                            app:elevation="0dp"
                            app:layout_anchor="@+id/nav_view"
                            app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
                            app:maxImageSize="40dp" />
                    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

Comment: can you explain abit how can you achieved the effect as image attached above?

Comment: I have used coordinator layout and added separate fab for big icon . So  it automates the coordination among its children like fab and helps to build this views.

Answer (score 0):

I have a complete solution for those who are looking for an answer.

1. Setup bottom_nav menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/home"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/shopFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shop"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/shop"/>

    // make the center icon have no title nor icon
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title=""/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notificationFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notification"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/notification"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/profile"/>

</menu>
```

2. Using `ConstraintLayout` align you center button to its bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_navhost_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fl_bottom_nav"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:elevation="4dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_main_bottom_nav"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_add_media"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_circle_outline_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/fl_bottom_nav"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result is something like this.
[image]

3. Call `iv_add_media`'s onclickListener in the activity

```
binding.ivAddMedia.setOnClickListener {
    // you can navigate to any fragment in the nav_graph
    // for my case I will open another activity
    navController.navigate(R.id.mediaActivity)
}
```

If there is any better solution please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use ConstraintLayout and apply

```
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

Refer https://riggaroo.dev/constraintlayout-guidelines-barriers-chains-groups/